# How to combine common rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm running some analysis on bank statements (csv's). Some items like McDonalds each have their own row (due to having different addresses).

I'm trying to combine these rows by a common phrase. So for this example the obvious phrase, or string, would be "McDonalds". I think it'll be an if statement.

Also, the column has a dtype of "object". Will I have to convert it to string format?

Here is an example output of the result of printing`totali = df.Item.value_counts()` from my code.

Ideally I'd want that line to output McDonalds as just a single row.
In the csv they are 2 separate rows.

```
foo                                   14
Restaurant Boulder CO                  8
McDonalds Boulder CO                   5
McDonalds Denver CO                    5
```

Here's what the column data consists of

```
'Sukiya Greenwood Vil CO' 'Sei 34179 Denver CO'  'Chambers Place Liquors 303-3731100 CO'  "Mcdonald's F26593 Fort Collins CO"  'Suh Sushi Korean Bbq Fort Collins CO'  'Conoco - Sei 26927 Fort Collins CO'
```

Comment: strings show up as object in dataframe...not to worry.  So you'd like to group by restaurant...  is the restaurant type (like "McDonalds") isolated in it's own column (series) in the data frame or is it as represented above where "McDonalds Boulder" and "McDonalds Denver" are in the series?  That will make it (a bit) more difficult to group.  Grouping is a complete snap if the field entries are exact same.

Comment: It would be helpful to get a look at the series (column) of data that you want to implement the groupings on...  can you edit your code with the result of `pd.<name>.unique()` where <name> is the name of the column containing the restaurants...

Comment: I've included the view of the data when I run ```df.Item.unique()```. Each item has it's own row in a csv. Strings show up as objects, got it. Thanks! 

Apologies I'm a beginner at this. I believe what you're asking is if each Item has it's own column. The column where the restaurants are is called "Item", so if I'm understanding your comment correctly it's going to be problematic to group

Comment: I see your edit.  you would NOT intend to group any of those items, right?  Are there more?  I'm assuming that is only partial list.  It will be a little difficult to group things if the strings with the names in them also contain the addresses, and that seems to be the case, correct?

Comment: Yup that's the case! I do not intend to group the example I provided, as they aren't the same places. That's the source of my confusion I guess. I'm trying to figure out how to group based on the first part of the string (restaurant name) or Zelle payments that have different senders, but would like them all to be under "Zelle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I think I ginned up something that can be helpful.  Realize that the task of inferring categories or names from text strings can be huge, depending on how detailed you want to get.  You can dive into `regex` or other learning models.  People make careers of it!  Obviously, your bank is doing some of this as they categorize things when you get a year-end summary.

Anyhow, here is a simple way to generate some categories and use them as a basis for the grouping that you want to do.

```
import pandas as pd


item=['McDonalds Denver', 'Sonoco', 'ATM Fee', 'Sonoco, Ft. Collins', 'McDonalds, Boulder', 'Arco Boulder']
txn = [12.44, 4.00, 3.00, 14.99, 19.10, 52.99]
df = pd.DataFrame([item, txn]).T
df.columns = ['item_orig', 'charge']
print(df)

# let's add an extra column to catch the conversions...
df['item'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)

# we'll use the "contains" function in pandas as a simple converter...  quick demo
temp = df.loc[df['item_orig'].str.contains('McDonalds')]
print('\nitems that containt the string "McDonalds"')
print(temp)

# let's build a simple conversion table in a dictionary
conversions = { 'McDonalds': 'McDonalds - any',
                'Sonoco': 'gas',
                'Arco': 'gas'}

# let's loop over the orig items and put conversions into the new column
# (there is probably a faster way to do this, but for data with < 100K rows, who cares.)
for key in conversions:
    df['item'].loc[df['item_orig'].str.contains(key)] = conversions[key]

# see how we did...
print('converted...')
print(df)

# now move over anything that was NOT converted
# in this example, this is just the ATM Fee item...
df['item'].loc[df['item'].isnull()] = df['item_orig']


# now we have decent labels to support grouping!
print('\n\n  *** sum of charges by group ***')
print(df.groupby('item')['charge'].sum())
```

#### Yields:

```
             item_orig charge
0     McDonalds Denver  12.44
1               Sonoco      4
2              ATM Fee      3
3  Sonoco, Ft. Collins  14.99
4   McDonalds, Boulder   19.1
5         Arco Boulder  52.99

items that containt the string "McDonalds"
            item_orig charge item
0    McDonalds Denver  12.44  NaN
4  McDonalds, Boulder   19.1  NaN
converted...
             item_orig charge             item
0     McDonalds Denver  12.44  McDonalds - any
1               Sonoco      4              gas
2              ATM Fee      3              NaN
3  Sonoco, Ft. Collins  14.99              gas
4   McDonalds, Boulder   19.1  McDonalds - any
5         Arco Boulder  52.99              gas


  *** sum of charges by group ***
item
ATM Fee             3.00
McDonalds - any    31.54
gas                71.98
Name: charge, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff! Definitely going to dissect your answer